# Continuous play of iTunes U audio files

Tags: iphone, ios, itunes-u

Is it possible to have the audio files from an iTunes U course play continuously; i.e., one after the other, without any user interaction, like a music playlist? At the moment, I can only play one at a time, but I would like to just have it playing, so I can listen in the car via BlueTooth (where I can't mess around with track selection).

I've not found any obvious way and Google didn't bring up anything useful/working suggestions. (This is on an iPhone 4 with iOS 7.2, if that makes a difference.)